# mysite.wsgi file is missing after creating django project

Tags: linux, django, nginx, uwsgi

I try to deploy nginx+uwsgi+django.
In .ini-file is required to set module=mysite.wsgi.
But in my project directory there is no any .wsgi-file.
Project created by

```
django-admin.py startproject xproj
```

Why it is possible?

Comment: Problem solved (permission denied).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Django 1.4.0 and above  wsgi.py exist under xproj->xproj  folder .

Django provided `wsgi.py` t interact with web server .

Answer (score 0):

Actually `wsgi.py` is the file you want. As you can see [here](https://www.quora.com/Where-is-Djangos-wsgi-file-I-see-only-wsgi-py-only).

> You see in Python people often use the Python module syntax when talking about files. So for example if you are talking about your `models[.]py` in a module named "Users" you wouldn't say `users/models[.]py` you would say users.models. This is what the gunicorn docs are doing. The writer of the docs is talking about the file `myproject/wsgi[.]py` but is using the module syntax of `myproject.wsgi`.