# How to start django server using wsgi.py, I'm trying to use gunicorn

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy my server (no longer in development) but I cannot figure out how to deploy it. Documentation from django's website recommends using gunicorn, but it seems like it might be outdated. Either that or I was viewing the tutorial for the wrong version of django. How do I deploy the non-development server using wsgi.py? Earlier it was suggested to me to follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28873121/mysite-wsgi-file-is-missing-after-creating-django-project) but it doesn't appear to actually describe how to go about using wsgi.py. Can someone explain to me how to deploy the server and if I need gunicorn?

Comment: You can refer this: [Deploy Django app with Nginx, Gunicorn, PostgreSQL & Supervisor](https://medium.com/hackernoon/deploy-django-app-with-nginx-gunicorn-postgresql-supervisor-9c6d556a25ac)

Comment: @AjayLingayat Thanks for the link, I am now getting a 403 error after following the tutorial though. I tried to chown the django project to www-data but that didn't help.